# Dart json_serializable Library Tries To Feed Nested Typed Lists a List<dynamic>

Tags: json, flutter, dart, json-deserialization

Just getting started with the json_serializable package (and Dart in general). I came across an issue where my simple entity blows up when trying to initialize it from JSON. The returned error is `trying to assign a List<dynamic> to a List<Asset>`.

```
test('Test AssetSearch Response Handling', () {
    String json = """{"recordsTotal":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"data":[{
          "assetType": "ASSET",
          "description": "A Case of Surgical Masks",
          "partNumber": "PN183289283",
          "serialNumber": "SN123"
        }]}""";
    AssetSearchResult result = AssetSearchResult.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
    expect(result.recordsTotal, equals(0));
    print("data returned was ${result.data}");
    expect(result.data.isEmpty, equals(true));
});
```

The Asset class looks like:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class AssetSearchResult {
  int recordsTotal;
  int recordsFiltered;
  List<Asset> data;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AssetSearchResultToJson(this);
  static fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AssetSearchResultFromJson(json);
}
```

...and finally the generated code from json_serializer is:

```
AssetSearchResult _$AssetSearchResultFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return AssetSearchResult()
    ..recordsTotal = json['recordsTotal'] as int
    ..recordsFiltered = json['recordsFiltered'] as int
    ..data = (json['data'] as List)   // <== This is where things blow up...
        ?.map(
            (e) => e == null ? null : Asset.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList();
```

If I change the generated code to wrap it in the proper List type, things work great.

```
    ..data = List<Asset>.from((json['data'] as List)
        ?.map(
            (e) => e == null ? null : Asset.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)));
```

I'm not sure how to fix this with annotations, or in the non-generated part of the entity, as the fix is inside the .g.dart class.